# Any other Picker controllers than ELCImagePickerController to select multiple images iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller

i have to select multiple images like 100 images from m iPad, if i used ELCImagePickerController my app is crashing because of too many images,

is there any other controller than ELCImagePicker to select multiple images, if so please let me know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try out:
http://www.binpress.com/app/agimagepickercontroller/784

Comment: by using this controller...how can we get the selected images...is there any delegate methods like didfinishpicking images like that..i didn't find any in this.

Comment: There is demo application on Git. Check it out: https://github.com/arturgrigor/AGImagePickerController/tree/master/AGImagePickerController%20Demo

Comment: Yes i checked this demo app but in this they are not showing how to get the selected images

Comment: I do not have dev environment with me but looking at the git code I noticed it calls: (void)didFinishPickingAssets:(NSArray *)selectedAssets  (which might be what you are looking for).  That all being said the best way to understand this code is to contact the author directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this, by commenting this line in ELCImagePickerController.m inside the selectedAssets function.

```
[workingDictionary setObject:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[[asset defaultRepresentation] fullScreenImage]] forKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
```

It creates a UIImage for each asset, which causes low memory crash when it loads a certain number of images.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [iOS multiple Image Picker](https://github.com/pigmasha/MAImagePicker).

- iOS 5.0 - 8.2 support
- using Photos.framework in iOS 8
- iPhone & iPad support